# R tm TermDocumentMatrix based on a sparse matrix

Tags: r, bash, text-mining, tm

I have a collection of books in txt format and want to apply some procedures of the `tm` R library to them. However, I prefer to clean the texts in bash rather than in R because it is much faster.

Suppose I am able to get from bash a data.frame such as:

```
book term frequency
--------------------
1     the      10
1     zoo      2
2     animal   2
2     car      3
2     the      20
```

I know that TermDocumentMatrices are actually sparse matrices with metadata. In fact, I can create a sparse matrix from the TDM using the TDM's i, j and v entries for the i, j and x ones of the sparseMatrix function. Please help me if you know how to do the inverse, or in this case, how to construct a TDM by using the three columns in the data.frame above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(tm)
library(reshape2)
txt <- readLines(n = 7)
book term frequency
--------------------
1     the      10
1     zoo      2
2     animal   2
2     car      3
2     the      20
df <- read.table(header=T, text=txt[-2])
dfwide <- dcast(data = df, book ~ term, value.var = "frequency", fill = 0)
mat <- as.matrix(dfwide[, -1]) 
dimnames(mat) <- setNames(dimnames(dfwide[-1]), names(df[, 1:2]))
(tdm <- as.TermDocumentMatrix(t(mat), weighting = weightTf))
# <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 4, documents: 2)>>
#   Non-/sparse entries: 5/3
# Sparsity           : 38%
# Maximal term length: 6
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

as.matrix(tdm)
#        Docs
# Terms     1  2
# animal    0  2
# car       0  3
# the      10 20
# zoo       2  0
```